# tensorflow first run issues

Tags: python, tensorflow, python-3.6

i just installed tesorflow cpu and heres my code

```
import tensorflow as tf
node1 = tf.constant(3.0)
node2 = tf.constant(4.0)
print(node1)
```

this doesnt run and the following error shows up:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Python\Python36\cssi\final_project.py", line 1, in <module>
    import tensorflow as tf
  File "c:\Python\Python36\cssi\tensorflow.py", line 2, in <module>
    node1 = tf.constant(3.0)
AttributeError: module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'constant'
```

please help

Comment: how did you install tensorflow?

Comment: i followed to tutorial on their website

Answer (score 1):

Just rename your script. I had the same problem when I created a script named **tensorflow.py**. Rename it to **test.py** and see how it works.

```
(base) D:\>python tensorflow.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "tensorflow.py", line 1, in <module>
    import tensorflow as tf
  File "D:\tensorflow.py", line 2, in <module>
    node1 = tf.constant(3.0)
AttributeError: module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'constant'

(base) D:\>python test.py
Tensor("Const:0", shape=(), dtype=float32)
```